# Is Shinsuusenju a summons?

Tags: naruto

Sage mode Hashirama's technique Shinsuusenju is called a senjutsu, or sage art. My question is does Hashirama actually create the titanic wooden budda statue with Moukton (wood style) or is it a creature he summons like Naruto's sumons Gamabunta? I always thought he created it, but I've seen many people refer to it as a summons. If any1 could clarify I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Look it yourself [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art_Wood_Release:_True_Several_Thousand_Hands).

Comment: @HappyFace link only replies (and answers) rarely help as they can become broken as time passes. Instead, try to summarize or quote the relevant parts to preserve the useful and relevant portions.

Answer (score 1):

According to Naruto Wiki Hashirama creates the statue using sage art wood release: true several thousand hands technique.

> After entering Sage Mode, Hashirama creates a wooden statue of titanic proportions

Link http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art_Wood_Release:_True_Several_Thousand_Hands from the comment of @HappyFace .